# How can I learn to play funk on a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I used to play piano when I was a kid, mostly classical education in a Gulbenkian conservatorium. Now I'm 24 and nurturing a deep love for Booker T's funky keyboards. Besides my piano, I have a M-Audio 61es on a Macbook Pro which I'll use to learn how to play funk.

Where should I go and which resources should I get to learn how to play Booker T-like funk? Are there any free websites or free online classes, videos, tutorials, exercises or (e)books that I should take?

Comment: Do you still play the piano at all?

Comment: Best is too subjective, so I edited to hopefully bring out more objective, explanatory answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This series of tutorial videos on YouTube is excellent:

They are probably the only decent ExpertVillage videos I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

As in any case when you're trying to play like artist X, listen to artist X, and try to play along. You'll need to train your ears to do this, but if you've played as much piano as I think you have, you should have sufficent muscle memory to be able to concentrate on the "hear it" part more than on the "play it" part.

Also check out this article on [B3 for pianists](http://www.keyboardmag.com/article/hammond-b-3-basics-for-pianists/2057) at Keyboard Magazine's website. Keyboard *very* often does features on specific instruments and styles.